# Mongodb Dot Notation Not Updating Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

I'm having a problem with mongodb's dot notation for arrays.

The 'bases' array in the user object has a set of bases in it which I'm trying to update via dot notation. To further complicate matters, I'm pushing the updates into an array of functions and calling them using the Async library.

```
//NOTE: baseIndex, baseData, dbCollection and baseOwner are considered defined already.
let updateArray = []
let thisUpdateObject = {}
thisUpdateObject['$set'] = {}
thisUpdateObject['$set']['bases.'+baseIndex] = baseData
let thisUpdate = function(callback){
    dbCollection.update({'id':baseOwner},thisUpdateObject,function(err, result){
        if (err){
            callback(err)
        } else {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}
updateArray.push(thisUpdate)
async.parallel(updateArray,function(err, results){
            if...
```

My result says the following:

```
n: 0,
nModified: 0,
ok: 1 }
```

I've verified that the bases array exists inside the document that matches 'id':baseOwner. Element zero does exist in the array (which shouldn't matter, but it does already exist.)

When I paste my update to console, I get this:

```
'$set': { 'bases.0': { *contains correct object*}}
```

Finally, I know that the async update system is working because in cases where dot notation is not included, the update **IS** correctly changing documents.

I'm assuming something's wrong with my dot notation, but I can't see what.

Am I making any obvious errors?

Comment: Notice the `n: 0` in your update result. That's telling you that your query isn't matching any documents. Ensure that `baseOwner` is of the expected value and type, and ensure that your use of `id` is correct and that you don't mean `_id`.

Comment: That was exactly the answer. ...Somehow my baseOwner got converted to a string instead of an int and it wasn't matching.
THANK YOU! (I've been staring at this too long.)

Comment: Haha, no problem. It's easy to get tunnel vision like that. Glad you found the answer you were looking for! I'll go ahead and submit what I mentioned here as an answer so we can mark this as solved :)

Comment: Please do. Appreciate the help.

Comment: For the record, if the value from `baseOwner` came from a form input from a webpage, then it's often the case that the default type for inputs is text. It's very common to expect a numeric value and actually receive a string in those cases. Tricky little bug right there!

Comment: Appreciate that addendum (and yeah, I've seen that happen myself).

In this case it was my own failure to properly parse an input I knew i should have parsed. Like I said, been staring at this thing too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief discussion in the comments yielded a simple answer:

The `n: 0` in the result indicates that no documents matched the update query. The culprit was an incorrect `id` value contained in the `baseOwner` variable.